# Posicionarse en una pestaña del navegador mediante javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, tengo una web /chat que lanza una notificacion al recibir un nuevo mensaje.

Si esa pestaña del navegador no está visible ( no tiene el foco ), necesito que al hacer click sobre ese cuadro de notificación, se abra la pestaña del navegador que ha realizado esa notificacion.

He probado a poner un alert() En el evento click de la notificacion , y funciona, ya que te lleva a la pestaña indicada, el problema es que es el usuario el que tiene que cerrar la alerta, y a mi me gustaria que se cerrara sola, o simplemente si hay otra forma de abrir la pestaña del navegador que queramos.

Ejemplo del código.

```
 var title = "Chat"
       var extra = {
           icon: urlDestination + "/images/Icon.png",
           body: "Tiene un mensaje nuevo de chat.",
           tag:"hola"
       }
       var noti = new Notification(title, extra);
       noti.onclick = function () {
           alert("s");
       }
       noti.onclose = {


       }
       setTimeout(function () { noti.close() }, 10000)
```

Tambien he probado con jquery ui dialog, pero eso no te abre la pestaña automaticamente.

¿Existe alguna manera de poner el foco en la pestaña del navegador que lanza este evento?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Simplemente con poner  window.focus(); en el evento onclick de la notificacion.